# Transaction isolation level REPEATABLE_READ using hibernate and jdbc

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, transactions

I am trying to develop a demo to cement my understanding of the REPEATABLE_READ isolation level. I have tried demos using hibernate and jdbc. JDBC works as expected, however hibernate does not.

My expectation is that, if i read a database row within one session, and i try to write the same row from another session, it should block until the first session finishes.

**Hibernate**:- When i 'get' an object (row) in Thread 0 and sleep, and within Thread 1 we try to update the same object (row), Thread 1 should wait till Thread 0 commits.

```
class HibernateExample7_IsolationRR_Read_Write_Thread implements Runnable {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HibernateExample7_IsolationRR_Read_Write_Thread.class);

    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    int sleep;
    int newnumberplate;
    public HibernateExample7_IsolationRR_Read_Write_Thread(SessionFactory sessionFactory, int sleep, int newnumberplate) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        this.sleep = sleep;
        this.newnumberplate = newnumberplate;
    }

    public void run() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        logger.info("TRYING TO GET VEHICLE 1");
        Vehicle vid1 = (Vehicle) session.get(Vehicle.class, Integer.valueOf(1));
        logger.info("GOT VEHICLE 1");
        vid1.setNumberplate(this.newnumberplate);
        logger.info("SET NUMBERPLATE FOR 1");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleep);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
        logger.info("COMMITED");
    }
}
```

hibernate.connection.url is **jdbc:derby:isolation;create=true** and hibernate.connection.isolation is **2**. I make two objects of HibernateExample7_IsolationRR_Thread, and i create a scenario where Thread 0 gets the vehicle and sleeps for long time. Meanwhile Thread 1 tries to get and update Vehicle. It successfully commits even before Thread 0 commits.

Due to the REPEATABLE_READ isolation level, shouldn't T1 wait on a commit. If not then it's a READ_COMMITED isolation level not a REPEATABLE_READ isolation level.

Comment: What version if hsqldb are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Your expectation is wrong. Repeatable read doesn't mean that a transaction should block while another transaction reads the same row. It means that reading the same row twice in the same transaction should return the same data, even if another transaction has committed a change to this row between the first and the second read.

You get that (more or less) for free with Hibernate, since the second read will return the data from the first-level cache, without going to the database at all.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29#Non-repeatable_reads

Also, you're making your test with a database that doesn't support this isolation level:

http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#N15385

Comment: Nitpicky: he'd be hitting second level cache, right? Each thread has its own session.

Comment: @sharakan: No. A single thread, getting the same entity twice in the same transaction, would hit the database the first time, and the first-level cache the second time. It would thus have repeatable reads, since the first-level cache will return the same data that was returned the first time (unless some changes have been made to the entity between the reads, of course).

Comment: Agreed, but he has two seperate threads, each of which call .openSession, and therefore have separate first level caches.

Comment: That's exactly my point. Each thread will have its own first level cache, and will thus be unaffected by what other threads do, which will lead to repeatable read inside a single thread, thanks to the first level cache not being shared with other threads.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.  I thought when you said this: "...since the second read will return the data from the first-level cache, without going to the database at all." you were referring to the read from the second thread in his example.  My mistake.

Comment: Hello JB. Repeatable read will NOT allow you to update a row which is being read by another transaction, until that transaction finishes. I have confirmed this by writing a small test in JDBC. Thanks for pointing out that hsqldb doesn't support REPEATABLE_READ. I am using 10.9.1.0 apache derby now. Hibernate on the other hand doesnt give me results that i am expecting and that is possibly due to the first level cache. In that case, whats the point of specifying REPEATABLE_READ isolation. I will update the question with new findings.

Comment: I disagree. Your database engine might ensure this isolation constraint by putting a lock on the row, but that's an implementation detail. What REPEATABLE_READ ensures is that two reads of the same row in the same transaction return the same data. Setting the isolation level with Hibernate is useful in situations where you disable the first-level cache, or refresh the entity, or read the data using a native query, i.e. every time you bypass the first-level cache.